# It is something people has/have? [Subject-Verb Agreement]

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

> It is something artists *has* to deal with.
>
> It is something artists *have* to deal with.

What should the auxiliary here be? The sentence has both a singular and a plural subject before the verb.

I would like to know how the proximity rule and the subject-verb agreement works in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

*It is something artists have to deal with*.

"Have" is correct.

There is no need to invoke a "proximity rule". The sentence consists of two clauses. There is an optional "that":

*It is something that artists have to deal with*.

"Artists" is the subject of the subordinate clause.